# child_process.exec ffmpeg hangs indefinitely

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

The following code hangs indefinitely:

```js
const pathToFfmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');
const { promisify } = require('util');
const exec = promisify(require('child_process').exec)

(async function() {
  console.log("Starting.");
  let outputLogs = await exec(`${pathToFfmpeg} -i input.mp4 output.gif`);
  console.log("Finished:", outputLogs);
})();
```

It worked the first time, but then silently hangs forever.

Comment: In cases like this, you should log the stdout and stderr to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `ffmpeg` is waiting for user input on whether to overwrite output.gif, which already exists. Pass the `-y` flag (which answers "yes" to the overwrite question automatically/non-interactively) like so:

```js
await exec(`${pathToFfmpeg} -y -i input.mp4 output.gif`);
```

(Creating this Q&A to hopefully prevent others like me from having to spend half an hour debugging this.)